# Second table association with code first migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How do I add a second table association using EF 6 code first?  I have a simple database for registering computers. Partial code is:

```
public class Person {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Computer> Computers { get; set; }
}
public class Computer {
    public virtual int Id{ get; set; }
    public virtual string Hostname { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Update-Database produces the tables as expected with a PersonId column in Computers. Then, the software requirements change (believe that?) and I need a primary contact in addition to an owner for each computer. So I updated Computer to:

```
public class Computer {
    public virtual int Id{ get; set; }
    public virtual string Hostname { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual Person Contact { get; set; }
}
```

Then run Add-Migrations and get the following:

```
public override void Up() {
    RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Computers", name: "Person_Id", newName: "Contact_Id");
    RenameIndex(table: "dbo.Computers", name: "IX_Person_Id", newName: "IX_Contact_Id");
}
```

It's highjacking my owner field for the contact!  I still need that.

I'm sure the right answer is RTM but the M is huge and this is a simple project that doesn't allow time for that.  If anyone has a simple answer to get me over this hurdle or has a link to the correct part of the docs that explain this, I'd be grateful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public class Computer 
{
    public virtual int Id{ get; set; }
    public virtual string Hostname { get; set; }
    ...
    public int OwnerId {get;set}
    public int? ContactId {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("OwnerId")]
    public virtual Person Owner{ get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ContactId")]
    public virtual Person Contact { get; set; }
}
```

But I am not 100% sure it will understand ICollection then correctly. But at least you can try.

UPDATE: I just tested it, seems ok for me. For your case you can avoid using 'OwnerId' and just add new foreign key for a Contact.

Comment: You are right!  I did have to remove the ICollection from person which means I have to update code so overall it is not a clean migration but I am no longer stuck.  Thanks!